# Ruby on Rails routing with multiple scope parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Edit: I've re-formulated my question a bit for clarity**

I have been handed a project kinda similar to ebay/amazon etc.. But where’s it’s of importance that users that belongs to a group model can use the whole site with a url like: `example.com/groupname/<all existing routes>`

Am I somehow on track with this route scoping? :

```rb
scope '(:locale)/(:group)', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')}/ do
...all routes..
end
```

And in the application_controller i have a before_action to validate the current_user's relationship with the group i fetch from the group param name.

**The question is**, would you guys do a scope or a namespace for this kinda thing? If I do a namespace I have to recreate new controllers/views right?

And if I'm using scope, how do I make the `link_to` helper not loose the (:group) param on all links in the view?

I would gladly appreciate some help on this topic!

Comment: did you tried to add namespace param like? <%= link_to(product_path(product, namespace), class: 'product-slider col-sm-3') do... %>

Comment: @Nezir I did like this instead: `link_to(product.try(:user).try(:name), user_url(id: product.try(:user).try(:id))) ` which seems to work better

Comment: @Carl `Product.featured` what does this returns?

Comment: I suggest that you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you get better answers.

Comment: @Gabbar it returned a list of product objects. I managed to fix those errors. However I've updated my question to maybe clarify better what my intentions was.